# Visual Studio 2019 Performance Profiler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a C# project using Linq to query SQL server, want to tackle some performance issue with performance profiler, however facing 2 problems

1. The instrumentation launching Internet Explorer, any way to change the browser setting?
2. The Database option greyed out in my performance profiler, Microsoft said "The Database tool requires Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 or later and a .NET Core project on Windows using either ADO.NET or Entity Framework Core."
   And I am using version 16.11.19, and I am using Linq in my project, so I guess this project is using Entity Framework Core

Any work around to fix the above problems?
(I am using visual studio 2019 community version)

[image: My Performance Profiler screen capture]

Comment: I don't understand why you don't choose to use .Net core project, maybe someone can answer your question better.